# Help checking whether some functions are probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Which of the next functions are cumulative distribution functions?

(а) $I_{\{x=0\}}$

(b) $F_X(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{c}0, x \in(-\infty, 0] \\ 1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}, x \in(n-1, n], n \in \mathbb{N}\end{array}\right.$

(c) $I_{\{x \in(0,+\infty)\}}$

Here are the propeties:

- $F(x)$ is non-decreasing;
- $F(x)$ is right-continuous;
- $0 \leq F(x) \leq 1$;
- $\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} F(x)=0$ and $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=1$; and
- $\operatorname{Pr}(a<X \leq b)=F(b)-F(a)$.

I think function (b) is not right continuous when $n=1$ at $x=0$. I understand function (a) and (c) are degerate distributions but I dont get what the $x$ mean in this notation.

Answer (score 0):

Examples (a) and (b) are both wrong because the functions are not non-decreasing. Example (c) is not right-continuous, so also bad.